# Во всех PictureBox отображается один и тот же Image, хотя должны разные

Tags: winforms, opencv, picturebox

На форме расположил pictureBox1. К проекту подключил библиотеку openCV.Через openCV произвожу захват видео и через Bitmap в цикле передаю в pictureBox1. Все работает. Вот код.

```
private: System::Void button11_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {

CvCapture* capture;

cvNamedWindow("original",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);    

capture = cvCreateFileCapture( filename);
while(1){

frame = cvQueryFrame( capture ); 
if( !frame ) {    
break;    
}    

myBitmap = gcnew System:rawing::Bitmap(frame->width,frame->height,frame->widthStep, System:rawing::Imaging::PixelFormat::Format24bppRgb,(System::IntPtr)frame->imageData);    

pictureBox1->Image = myBitmap;    

cvWaitKey(40);

}

cvReleaseCapture( &capture );
cvDestroyWindow("original"); 
}
```

Теперь хочу раскадровать видео. Естественно,по аналогии в каждом цикле создаю новый pictureBox и опять же каждый Bitmap цикла загружаю в pictureBox созданный в этом цикле.
Вот измененный код:

```
private: System::Void button11_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
int k;
CvCapture* capture;

cvNamedWindow("original",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);    

capture = cvCreateFileCapture( filename);
while(1){

PictureBox^picBox = gcnew PictureBox();
picBox= gcnew System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox();
picBox ->Location = System:rawing::Point(10+k*81,500);
picBox->Size = System:rawing::Size(80,60);
// picBox->TabIndex = k+3;
picBox->BorderStyle = BorderStyle::FixedSingle;
picBox->SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode::StretchImage; 
Controls->Add(picBox);


frame = cvQueryFrame( capture ); 
if( !frame ) {    
break;    
}

myBitmap = gcnew System:rawing::Bitmap(frame->width,frame->height,frame->widthStep, System:rawing::Imaging::PixelFormat::Format24bppRgb,(System::IntPtr)frame->imageData);      

picBox->Image = myBitmap;    

cvWaitKey(40);
k++;
}

cvReleaseCapture( &capture );
cvDestroyWindow("original");
}
```

В результате pictureBox'ы создаются, но во всех отображается только первый кадр.
Где у меня ошибка? Как ее исправить?

Answer (score 0):

Прошу прощения у всех,кому доставил беспокойство своим вопросом - в данном фрагменте кода ошибки нет! Ошибка была в другом месте. Простоя ,по-глупости, создал две переменные myBitmap (локальная и глобальная), и в создающиеся picBox'ы заносил глобальную.Поэтому и получал множество pictureBox с одинаковым изображением